# Looking for trails that are open in Iceland in mid-March for a multi-day hike?

Tags: winter, backcountry, iceland

Looking for trails that are open in mid-March for a multi-day hike. I believe Laugavegur is closed, and I haven't found much in the way of marked trails.

Comment: Did you end up finding some trails?

Answer (score 3):

In March Iceland would still be covered in snow and ice with daily highs of 3*c on the south coast and an average temperature of around 0*c. Most days it snows.

[Daily High and Low Temperature in March](https://weatherspark.com/averages/27562/3/Reykjavik-Capital-Region-Iceland) for Reykjavík, Iceland

[image: Daily High and Low Temperature in March]

You might be able to ski tour if you have the skills to survive in arctic weather, but I highly doubt you'd be able to hike, even on the southern coast.